# Hibernate mapping with foreign key table

Tags: java, hibernate, join, mapping, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a hbm.xml to map some persistent objects in java with hibernate.

My Domain looks like this:

A **Property** has a **Folder** which has root **Folders**. **Property** has a key to find the **Folder** and **Folder** has a key to find its root **Folders**.

```
public class Property {
  private Folder folder;
  private Set<Folder> rootFolders;
}

public class Folder {
   private String id;
   private String rootfolder;
   private String descriptor;
}
```

Now there is a *Folder.hbm.xml* (and *Folder.java*), but I can't change it and I can't add a reference there (untouchable legacy). So I can't add the list of roots there.

I want to add it in the **Property** directly though, so that **Property** has two fields, **folder** and **rootFolders**.

I tried with *join* and *set* (see further down), but I can't get Hibernate to create the correct Query...
So my question is: Is this possible with mapping (I don't want to use HQL) and how would that look like?

**EDIT**: I figured out that a Folder has a list of Folders (and changed the description accordingly). 
The code I have as far is:

```
<set name="rootFolders" table="FOLDER">
        <key column="ID" property-ref="folder.id"/>
        <many-to-many 
            column="ROOTFOLDER"
            class="org.company.Folder"
            property-ref="descriptor"
            />
</set>
```

I already mapped the **Folder** to the **Property** (and called it *folder*). **Folder** has a column **ROOTFOLDER** which maps on **DESCRIPTOR** of a **Folder** (which is not a primary key though!).

In addition I tried to do the necessary retrieval with SQL (just to make sure it's possible):

```
from 
(select t.logical_id, t.id, t.tariffroot from (PROPERTY p inner join FOLDER f on p.FOLDER_ID = f.ID)) propertyFolders
inner join FOLDER roots on propertyFolders.FOLDERROOT= roots.DESCRIPTOR
```

Comment: Which references exists already in the Folder, and which reference do you want to add?

Comment: Do you need more information?

Comment: You lost a word here: "I tried with xxx, but "